# sftp: command to select desired files to copy

Tags: linux, command-line, file-copy, sftp

I have a long list of data files that I need to copy over to my server, they have the names

```
data_1.dat
data_2.dat
data_3.dat
...
data_100.dat
```

Starting from `data_1.dat`, I would like to get all the files where the number is increased by 3, i.e. `data_4.dat`, `data_7.dat`, `data_10.dat`, ...

Is there a way to specify this? Right now I am doing in manually using  `get data_4.dat`, but there must be a way to automatize this.

Comment: create a list with using `seq 1 3 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux:

```
printf -- '-get data_%d.txt\n' $(seq 1 3 100) | sftp -b - user@example.com
```

On BSD (with no `seq(1)` in sight):

```
printf -- '-get data_%d.txt\n' $(jot 100 1 100 3) | sftp -b - user@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` supports C style looping construct, you can leverage that:

```
for ((i=1; i<=100; i+=3)); do echo file_$i.dat; done
```

Replace `echo file_$i.dat` with the operation you want on the file.

---

**Example:**

```
$ for ((i=1; i<=100; i+=3)); do echo file_$i.dat; done
file_1.dat
file_4.dat
file_7.dat
file_10.dat
file_13.dat
file_16.dat
file_19.dat
file_22.dat
file_25.dat
file_28.dat
file_31.dat
file_34.dat
file_37.dat
file_40.dat
file_43.dat
file_46.dat
file_49.dat
file_52.dat
file_55.dat
file_58.dat
file_61.dat
file_64.dat
file_67.dat
file_70.dat
file_73.dat
file_76.dat
file_79.dat
file_82.dat
file_85.dat
file_88.dat
file_91.dat
file_94.dat
file_97.dat
file_100.dat
```